# regex to remove x-hrefs of a certain value

Tags: javascript, regex

I am displaying emails on an a page from an html string.

Certain href attribute values are causing me problems.  They take the form of `x-msg://1726/`, for example they might appear like this:

```
<base href="x-msg://1726/">
```

I want to replace all the href tags of this protocol with a simple #.

How can I specify in a regex that I want to match on an href attribute that matches the x-msg protocol and replace it with an empty string or # symbol?

I want to do this in javascript.

Comment: Be more precise, what do you want to match? What do you want to replace?

Comment: Are you trying to identify the elements or the `href` itself?  What do you have to work with to find the `href`s?  A string?  A document object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JavaScript you can use grouping in replace to reuse matched strings.

```
str = str.replace(/(href=")x-msg:\/\/([^"]+)\//ig', '$1#$2');
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/9l6k0n)

In your example, the result would be `<base href="x-msg://1726/">`.  If you're confident that x-msg is only in the href's, then you can certainly reduce the complexity of the regex by removing all of the html markup from the regex.  Also I don't know if x-msg could include alpha-numeric characters, or just numeric as in your example.  Using `\d` or set that matches specified characters would be best.

Answer (score 0):

A potential regexp is this one:

```
/href ?= ?"x-msg:\/\/\d+\/"/
```

Example here: http://regex101.com/r/aJ5gZ6